# MOSS 2007 - Should I create a custom workflow or not?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have a scenario where I want a user when viewing a list item to be presented with a custom action to create a site. This is pretty similar to the scenario provided in the MOSS 2007 SharePoint Guidance. What makes it different is that I want the site created with the url and name taken from the list item, and then a web propertybag value set. The only user task after the site is created is for the site collection administrator to add some specific user rights to it.

I can do everything apart from prompting the user to set the site rights via the object model so should I use a workflow or just code it straight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefits of a workflow would be the ability to track the task and whether it has been completed or needs escalation etc.

The answer to this question is going to be found from your own staff on how they want to manage the tasks. An email notification may suite them better. Check with them on whether the benefits of a workflow are going to be worth the development cost.